# How do you stop colspan on whole column auto adjusting width?

Tags: html

I need each column to maintain its starting width, even when introducing colspan. Must be dynamic as this could occur multiple times in the same table.

This is my desired result
[image]

See jsfiddle for code example and current result 
https://jsfiddle.net/vh82sjhj/1/

```
 /* this is where the problem arises */    
<td class="tile_td" id="00" rowspan="4" colspan="2"></td>
```

Comment: refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257308/why-is-colspan-not-applied-as-expected

Comment: Thanks @shaochuancs. For anyone else that finds themselves here in the same situation, adding <col width='+col_width+'> fixed my issue, in this case col_width = 25%.