# Vue template colspan not working properly

Tags: css, vue.js, html-table, frontend

Hi im having a issue with a simple problem. because for some reason i dont find anything wrong with my codes. Seems like my code is not reading my colspan. seems like this problem as been mark as duplicate. but i dont want to specify the width of the table since i want the table to be responsive and i use bootstrap table

```
<div>
  <table class="table table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr class="text-uppercase text-contrail table-dark-head">
          <th colspan="3">Spillage</th>
          <th>Total</th>
          <th>Remarks</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td colspan="3">Material Cost / Kg</td>
           <td>
             <input></input>
           </td>
           <td>
             <input></input>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Spillage at 0.5%</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

i put this code inside my template. please see the image for the result. The Total and Remarks should be on the right side. but it end up with balance width.

[image: table result sample]

Comment: Already answered, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257308/why-is-colspan-not-applied-as-expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is colspan not applied as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257308/why-is-colspan-not-applied-as-expected)

Comment: Seems like we are different. i dont want to specify the table width because i want the table to be responsive and i use bootstrap

Comment: You should set the column's width manually, otherwise, they will be adjusted to fit the content.