# HTML table validation colspan issue

Tags: html, html-table, w3c-validation

I have this html table:

```
<fieldset class="form login">
    <legend>Authorization</legend>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">
            <label class="form__label" for="login">Login</label>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3">
            <input id="login" type="email" required="required">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="1">
            <label class="form__label" for="password">Password</label>
          </td>
          <td colspan="3">
            <input id="password" type="password" required="required">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center" colspan="4"><input type="submit"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
```

When I run it through validator (validator.w3.org) I get an error:

```
Error: Table columns in range 3…4 established by element td have no cells beginning in them.

From line 21, column 16; to line 22, column 26

     </td>↩          <td colspan="3">↩
```

What does it mean ?
I found this answer:
[Help with HTML validation error: Table column has no cells beginning in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292947/help-with-html-validation-error-table-column-has-no-cells-beginning-in-it)

but still don't understand what exactly I must do to make it valid ?

Comment: probably coz the number of columns you want to span is less then the number of columns in the table. try expanding the table of decreasing the value of colspan

Comment: decreased colspan 3 to 2 - doesen't work, in fact, getting more errors:
A table row was 4 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your table has three rows:

  ```
  Row 1:
  Row 2:
  Row 3:
  ```
- In rows 1 and 2 you have a cell in column 1 and a cell spanning columns 2 to 4
- In row 3 you have a cell spanning columns 1 to 4

  ```
  Row 1: | cell 1,1 | cell 1,2-4 |
  Row 2: | cell 1,1 | cell 1,2-4 |
  Row 3: | cell 1,1-4            |
  ```
- The validator looks at this table and complains that although the markup says that there are 4 columns in reality there are only 2.

So the solution is to replace `colspan="3"` in rows 1 and 2 with `colspan="1"` (or drop it altogether, since `colspan="1"` is meaningless), and in row 3 replace `colspan="4"` with `colspan="2"`. In this way the markup is aligned with the actual aspect of the table.